# Visual studio code wants me to install the same update everytime I launch it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I already have installed 1.69.1 but everytime I open vs code it wants me to install the same 1.69.1 update and even after installing it again if I close the app and relaunch it, the install updates pops up down there in the settings section

Is this a bug in this version or my pc is having problems? and how to solve it so it doesn't tell me to install the same updates over

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using this version but don't have this problem and my OS is macOS Big Sur.
Maybe you can change the update policy of VSCode, set it as follows.

1. Click Settings, then type update: Mode
2. change the update policy to manual or none (manual is recommended)